# Reassign ribbon buttons in Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a number of custom buttons on a custom ribbon tab in Outlook 2010 to run a variety of macros. Unfortunately, if I ever rename a macro, or move it between modules to keep them better organised, my buttons stop working and I have to recreate them from scratch to restore functionality.

Is there any way to change or reassign which macro these buttons run after they've been added?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see is to export your ribbon customizations, edit the resulting .exportedUI file (onAction for your buttons) and import the file back.